# Autocovariance of the process $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

> Let $ \{X_t, t=1,2,...\} $ be a stationary process. Obtain the autocovariance function of  $ Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1} $.\

**Solution.** Since $ X_t $ is stationary, then $ E(X_t) $ is constant and $ Cov(X_t, X_s) $ depends on $s$ and $t$ only through $|s-t|$. Anyway, the autocovariance is

\begin{align}
\gamma_Y(s,t) &= Cov(Y_t, Y_s)  \\ 
 &= Cov(X_t - X_{t-1}, X_s - X_{s-1}) \\
 &= Cov(X_t, X_s) - Cov(X_t, X_{s-1}) - Cov(X_{t-1}, X_s) + Cov(X_{t-1}, X_{s-1}) \\
 &= \gamma(t,s) - \gamma(t, s-1) - \gamma(t-1, s) + \gamma(t-1, s-1).
\end{align}

I know the derivation is incomplete because I didn't use the hypothesis that $X_t$ is stationary. I contacted my professor and he said "since the $X_t$ is stationary, you can write the autocovariance function as a function of the lag, and combine the covariances that appear in the last equation". I'm not sure how to do that, though.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Because $X_t$ is stationary by hypothesis, then $\gamma(t,s-1)=\gamma(t-1,s) = \gamma(1)$. For the same reason, $\gamma(t-1,s-1) = \gamma(t,s)$, so we can simplify the last expression as

$$
\gamma_Y(t,s) = 2\gamma(t,s) - 2\gamma(1)
$$

which depends on $t$ and $s$ only through $|s-t|$, also proving that $Y_t$ is stationary.