# Weak stationarity of difference of weak stationary process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

If I have discrete weakly stationary process $X_t$:

- expected value is finite
- variance is finite
- $\textrm{cov}(X_p,X_q)=\gamma(|p-q|),\forall p,q\in\mathbb{N}$.

Can I be sure that it's difference $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$ is also weakly stationary?

Comment: Question should be closed https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213826/autocovariance-of-the-process-y-t-x-t-x-t-1?rq=1

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [Autocovariance of the process $Y_t = X_t - X_{t-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4213826/autocovariance-of-the-process-y-t-x-t-x-t-1)